# how can i submit job to hadoop cluster from web application?

Tags: hadoop

I have a Map Reduce program embedded into the Apache Tomcat web container. But while running the program it runs as local job runner instead of running on cluster with jobClient .
Please help me to submit job to remote cluster. What is process for submitting the job and configuration set up in to the java program ?

Answer (score 0):

Hadoop runs in local mode when it can not find it's configuration. When it can find it it takes there among other things JobTracker's adress
You can put mapred-site xml on your /etc/hadoop/conf/ directory 
or set JobTracker URL in the job's configuration explicitly.

Comment: Thanks for reply.I tried by putting the jobtracker configuration in the program but then it gives Mapper class not found . Is it necessary to create jar file to submit job to hadoop cluster?

Comment: Yes, you have to create jar and call "setJarbyClass" to let hadoop know what jar to send.